# Edit list element in multilist - Python

Tags: python, list

I am using python 3.x, I have the following problem, using the keyboard the user enters certain data and fills N lists to create a contact list, then in a list I collect all the data of the lists, I need to modify the data of each list, (I already have it, I modify the data of a list with a specific value using a for) Example, Names list, I modify Andrew's name, but in the Contacts list, there is all Andrew's information (phone, mail, etc), but I just need to modify in the Contacts list, the value of Andrew
I have all this list:

```
names = []
surnames = []
phones = []
emails = []
addresses = []
ages = []
salaries = []
genres = []
contacts = []
# and use the append to add the data into the contacts list
contacts.append ([names, surnames, phone numbers, emails, addresses, ages, salaries, genders])
```

Then I update the info of one contact

```
search = input(Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "Type the name of the contact you want update: ")
    for i in range(len(names)):
        if (names[i] == search):
                try:
                    names[i] = input(Fore.MAGENTA + "Type the New name: ")
                    names[i] = nombres[i].replace(" ", "")
               if names[i].isalpha() == True:
                    print(Fore.GREEN + "Already saved, congrats.")
                    pause= input(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + "Press enter to exit")
```

But I dont know how to update the name in the List of contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `contacts.append()`, you add a list of lists to a list, so your `contacts` list will look something like this:

```py
contacts = [[[names[0], names[1], ...], [...], [...]]]
```

It's unnecessary to have a list of one item nested in another list, so I would just call `contacts.append()` and pass each list (`names`, `surnames`, etc.) to the method, which allows for easier indexing.

Since the list `names` would be the first item in the list `contacts` (`contacts[0]`), you could do one of two things (there may be more, but these are off the top of my head):

1. Reassign the specific index to a new value, using nested-list indexing (`contacts[0][0] = "updated name"` would update the first item of the `names` list to `"update name"`)
2. Reassign the entire nested list to a new list (`contacts[0] = new_name_list` would reassign `contacts[0]`, formerly the `names` list, to `new_name_list`)

On a side note: In this case, I would recommend dictionaries over lists, as it will be easier to keep track of what is being reassigned/modified.

```py
contacts = {
    "names": names,
    "surnames": surnames,
    ...
}
```

Doing this will make it more clear which list your are referring to; `contacts[0]` doesn't give much information, but `contacts["names"]` informs readers that you are referring to the `names` list. This is solely for cleaner code; there isn't much difference in functionality.